# File upload to flask API with fetch API - request.files is empty

Tags: javascript, python, flask, fetch-api

I have been trying to upload files to a Flask API with the javascript fetch API.

I am forming the request like this:

```
    let file = new FormData();
    let imageFile = document.getElementById("select-image").files[0];
    file.append("file", imageFile);
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/image-file',
      {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          'Authorization': token
        },
        body: file
      })
      .then(async http => {
        let response = http.text();
        if (http.ok) {
          console.log("created")
          postImageData(text);
        }
        else {
          return response.then(response => {throw new Error(response);})
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
```

but when I do `request.files` in flask, the object is empty, and `request.files["file"]` returns an error.

Inspecting the request, the payload looks like this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryG7nrDvgPSk3FSRUs
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="2480_books2.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryG7nrDvgPSk3FSRUs--
```

My file upload element looks like this:

```
<input id="select-image" name="image" type="file"/><br/>
```

Can I access the file from the request as it is, or is there a problem with the request itself?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it - in case anyone else comes across this issue it turns out the solution is extremely simple: just remove the Content-Type header from the fetch request, as the type is handled automatically.

Answer (score -1):

"Note that files will only contain data if the request method was POST, PUT or PATCH and the  that posted to the request had enctype="multipart/form-data". It will be empty otherwise."

Perhaps enctype="multipart/form-data" is missing from the form tag

Edit: Sorry if i couldn't help, i only know Python and C (currently learning). Glad you're able to fix it :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I am using the fetch API within javascript rather than a html form element in the page. I manually create the form data element and add the header `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` to set that. Let me know if I am missing something though :)